# Access 2007 Validation rules

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to make a field put a certain name in when a different field has a certain text in Access 2007.  Eg.

```
If [FieldName] = "mountain" then [FieldName2] ="Jack" but if [FieldName] = "ocean" then [FieldName2] ="John"
```

I can't find an expression that will give me this result.

Comment: Use an else if. `IIf [FieldName] = "ocean" then [FieldName2] = "John" else if [FieldName] = "mountain" then [FieldName2] = "Jack"`

Comment: @TahTatsumoto I am entering the following and I'm getting an invalid syntax.  Any idea where I'm going wrong?  If ([Product Category]="Children") Then 
[Category Manager] ="John" 
Elseif ([Product Category] = "Hybrid") Then 
[Category Manager] = "Jack" 
Elseif ([Product Category]="Leisure") Then 
[Category Manager] = "Sally" 
Elseif ([Product Category] = "Mtn.") then 
[Category Manager] = "Kelly"
Else ([Category Manager]="Carl")
End If

Comment: That's a lot of `if` statements. I'd recommend changing it to a `case` statement. Here's how you'd use them http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/case.php

Answer (score 1):

It's better to change multiple `if-then` statements to case/switch statements.

```
Select Case [Product Category]
    Case "Children"
        [Category Manager] = "John"
    Case "Hybrid"
        [Category Manager] = "Jack"
    Case "Leisure"
        [Category Manager] = "Sally"
    Case "Mtn."
        [Category Manager] = "Kelly"
    Case Else
        [Category Manager] = "Carl"
End Select
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. #SOReadyToHelp. Would appreciate if you mark my answer as accepted.